# How can I clear Steam achievements for Portal 2?

Tags: steam, achievements, portal-2

My brother has played Portal 2 on my account and got a decent chunk of the achievements without specifically trying for them.  Shamefully, I haven't yet played it, but I want to of course.  I really enjoyed getting all the achievements in the first game and want to try for them in the second, but I want the regular Steam alerts to show up when I get one so that I know for sure that I got it.  Naturally, this won't happen for any achievements that my brother already got.

Thus my question: Can I clear Steam achievements (set them all back to unachieved), so that I'll get alerts and be able to track them properly?  I know I can clear the game progress that's saved via Steam Cloud but I don't want to do that since it would destroy my brother's progress, and I know there are some issues syncing the achievements between the game and Steam anyways.

Comment: That's too bad, and it's a shame Steam is so single-player-per-game about everything. Portal 2 has quite a lot of meta-humor in the achievements.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

From the [Steam FAQ](https://support.steampowered.com/kb_article.php?ref=4462-UIOB-0425):

> **Resetting Achievements**
>   Unfortunately, achievements can not be reset at this time.

Answer (score 4):

Using a third party program it is possible to reset your achievements as they are NOT stored server-side. **Though extremely unlikely, it is possible to be banned for doing this**. As of July 2015 I don't believe Steam is banning for using SAM.

http://gib.me/sam/